# JXTreeTable not showing my data

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

> Here is my code what wrong in it

```
DemoJFrame.java

package com.suru;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.TreeTableModel;

public class DemoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable treeTable;
    private final TreeTableModel gen;

    public DemoJFrame() {
        gen = new TreeTableGen();
        initComponents();
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        treeTable = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("JXTreeTable Demo");
        treeTable.setTreeTableModel(gen);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(treeTable);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DemoJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class DataBean {
    int id;
    String data;
    int amount;
}

public class MainDataBean {
    int id;
    String name;
    int total;
    ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeans;
}


//MyTableModelGenerator

package com.suru;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.DefaultTreeTableModel;

public class TreeTableGen extends DefaultTreeTableModel {

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[]{
        "ID", "Name", "Amount"
    };
    ArrayList<MainDataBean> arrayList;

    public TreeTableGen() {
        // data source class
        // printing data below
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        arrayList = dataSource.getMainDataBeans();

        for (MainDataBean bean : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(bean);
            ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeans = bean.getDataBeans();
            for (DataBean dataBean : dataBeans) {
                System.out.println(dataBean);
            }
            System.out.println("==========================================");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return node instanceof DataBean;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMNS[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMNS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object node, int columnIndex) {
        if (node instanceof MainDataBean) {
            MainDataBean data = (MainDataBean) node;
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                return data.getId() + "";
            } else if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return data.getName();
            } else if (columnIndex == 2) {
                return data.getTotal() + "";
            } else {
                return "data not found! at 1";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof DataBean) {
            DataBean data = (DataBean) node;
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                return data.getId() + "";
            } else if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return data.getData();
            } else if (columnIndex == 2) {
                return data.getAmount() + "";
            } else {
                return "data not found! at 2";
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        return ((MainDataBean) parent).getDataBeans().get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if (parent instanceof MainDataBean) {
            return ((MainDataBean) parent).getDataBeans().size();
        } else {
            return arrayList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        MainDataBean pa = ((MainDataBean) parent);
        DataBean ch = ((DataBean) child);
        ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeans = pa.getDataBeans();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataBeans.size(); i++) {
            DataBean dataBean = dataBeans.get(i);
            if (dataBean.getId() == ch.getId()) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}


my output in console as follows:

MainDataBean{id=1, name=bean1, total=2974}
DataBean{id=10, data=val (1, 0), amount=900}
DataBean{id=11, data=val (1, 1), amount=104}
DataBean{id=12, data=val (1, 2), amount=861}
DataBean{id=13, data=val (1, 3), amount=947}
DataBean{id=14, data=val (1, 4), amount=162}
==========================================
MainDataBean{id=2, name=bean2, total=2215}
DataBean{id=20, data=val (2, 0), amount=141}
DataBean{id=21, data=val (2, 1), amount=196}
DataBean{id=22, data=val (2, 2), amount=769}
DataBean{id=23, data=val (2, 3), amount=146}
DataBean{id=24, data=val (2, 4), amount=963}
==========================================
MainDataBean{id=3, name=bean3, total=2816}
DataBean{id=30, data=val (3, 0), amount=810}
DataBean{id=31, data=val (3, 1), amount=675}
DataBean{id=32, data=val (3, 2), amount=895}
DataBean{id=33, data=val (3, 3), amount=290}
DataBean{id=34, data=val (3, 4), amount=146}
==========================================
MainDataBean{id=4, name=bean4, total=1537}
DataBean{id=40, data=val (4, 0), amount=38}
.....
.....
but it is not reflecting in my frame
```

> my output screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing DefaultTreeTableModel the root node.

As a result, DefaultTreeTableModel is making its own empty root node and then you're not adding anything to that either.

You could either add something to the root node or add your own root node.